# Java socket output stream

Tags: java, sockets, networking

Can you have an `PrintWriter` and `ObjectOutputStream` on the same sockets output stream?

```
out_stream = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
obj_stream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* but you have to take care of buffering. A `PrintWriter` or an `ObjectOutputStream` accepts data, which it converts into bytes, to be sent on the underlying stream (here the socket) *at some point*. Buffering is about waiting a bit before writing out such bytes, so that the bytes can be sent in "big chunks" rather than individually.

Read the Javadoc about buffering, and use `flush()` on `PrintWriter` and `ObjectOutputStream` when you want to get sure that the bytes get written on the socket.

Answer (score 3):

I would say yes but I don't think I would do it.

What is it you want to do?

Comment: Here is what I have done so far  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8272726/distributed-system, I am now trying to implement that the worker machines have to be sent the 'doSomething()' method from the manager. I thought I could achieve this by sending an object using the ObjectOutputStream class?

Comment: @sudo_o I still don't really see the need to mix them, it just adds complexity in the other end when you need to read some data as objects and some as text. But good luck: -)

Comment: There isn't a need, My framework passes strings the way I want it to and I don't want to break that. Now I'm trying to send an object but instead of changing all of the `PrintWriters` in my classes I am keeping it separate whilst I work on it. However when I try and send an object `w_obj.writeObject(obj);` it throws and `IOExpection`.

Comment: Reading further on this topic I have discovered that `obj` has to implement serializable `public class obj implements Serializable`

Comment: @sudo_o yes, that's a prerequisite for being able to use serialization and write object on a stream.

Comment: Thanks for your help, my first networking application is coming along nicely!